# Collinearity and Betweenness

Tags: geometry

In "Geometry" by Harold R. Jacobs the definition of betweenness of points is given:

*Point B is between point $A$ and $C$ iff $A$, $B$ and $C$ are collinear and $AB + BC = AC$*

The definition of collinearity is given:

*Points that lie on the same line are called **collinear** points.*

Isn't the requirement for the lines to be collinear redundant? $AB + BC = AC$ could only be satisfied if they all lie on the same line. Other wise $AB + BC > AC$ (triangle inequality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have that book, I haven't even read it, so I have to guess. But my guess would be that at that point, adding lengths on a line has been defined while adding arbitrary lengths has not. So in order to avoid cyclic dependencies, he adds that collinearity as a requirement, can then provide this definition and can later on use that definition to define and/or prove other stuff, e.g. how to add arbitrary lengths.

It could also be that at that point he is defining things which might be used for geometries other than our well-known Euclidean one. E.g. geometries on curved surfaces or something like this. In that case, not requiring the triangle inequality to hold might be useful since it makes the definition more widely applicable.

Comment: Thanks! The triangle inequality wasn't introduced at that point in the book - I just used it. But assuming that we are dealing with Euclidean geometry. Would the definition:
Point B is between point A and C iff AB+BC=AC. Be a correct one as well?